# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftCore.dylib problem with new Xcode (10.2)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

None of the referenced answers works. Something new has happened with Xcode 10.2

This happens whether or not I use Swift 4.2 or 5.

It happens immediately with a brand new, unedited command-line tool.

All you need to do, is create a MacOS command-line tool, and hit "run."

You immediately get this error.

Nothing I have done so far has fixed it.

Comment: Are you on macOS 10.4.3? Did you install (or update) the “Swift Runtime For Command Line Tools”?

Comment: I am on 10.14.3

Comment: I have run the updater. Is there a new step I need to take? I'll look.

Comment: Read the first paragraph in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2: “Starting with Xcode 10.2, Swift command line tools require the Swift libraries in macOS. ...”

Comment: Excellent! I think that's what I needed to do (RTFM). Make that an answer, and I'll greencheck you. Thanks!

Comment: I got this problem as well with the new xcode 10.2, my project suddenly has this error, but it only affecting one particular branch not all. so yeah its weird

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [Swift 5 Release Notes for Xcode 10.2](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2):

> **Swift 5 Runtime Support for Command Line Tools Package**
>
> Starting with Xcode 10.2, Swift command line tools require the Swift libraries in macOS. They’re included by default starting with macOS Mojave 10.14.4. In macOS Mojave 10.14.3 and earlier, there’s an optional package to provide these runtime support libraries for Swift command line tools that you can download from [More Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/). If you installed the beta version of this package, replace it with the release version. This package is only needed for Swift command line tools, not for apps with graphical user interfaces.

Note that:

- This is *only* necessary if you are still on macOS 10.14.3. As soon as macOS is upgraded to 10.14.4, the Swift runtime libraries are provided by the operating system, and command line tools created with Xcode 5 run without the need to install the “Swift 5 Runtime package.”
- On macOS 10.14.3 with Xcode 10.2 you must download and install the *latest* “Swift 5 Runtime package.” An earlier package which you might have installed with an Xcode 10.2 beta release does not work.
- Early versions of the Xcode 10.2 beta release notes recommended to add a user-defined setting `SWIFT_FORCE_STATIC_LINK_STDLIB=YES`  as a workaround, that is no longer necessary.

Comment: Yeah...still happens. Maybe I'll need to upgrade to 10.14.4. I don't know if that version has been released yet.
I assumed that these were what was installed when I ran the installer.
I'll reboot the Mac. That often fixes these types of issue.

Comment: @LittleGreenViper: I am already on 10.14.4 so I cannot reproduce it. Did you install the Swift 5 Runtime package from March 25?

Comment: OK. That did it. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated to 10.14.4 but still the problem persist. any workaround?

Comment: same here, updated to 10.14.4, after that to Xcode 10.2 and it still crashes

Comment: @FabioBerger: With the same error message? Also with a command-line tool project?

Comment: @MartinR Same error message, but it's not a command line tool, it's from a custom framework. But the error is only happening on the device, when I try on the simulator it works fine..

Comment: Not sure why it still crashes after 10.14.4. That *SHOULD* work without installing the new library.

In any case, you need to install the "Swift 5 Runtime Support for Command Line Tools" DMG, not the one below it (which is installed when you first start Xcode).

This is only supposed to be necessary for OS levels below .4

Comment: In my case, the OS did not seem to "get" it until I had restarted.

Comment: Oh. Reading comprehension. I've heard of it. @FabioBerger: It's entirely possible that your issue is different from mine. Mine was for a MAC OS command-line tool. There's no "on device." There's a ton of stuff about the same symptom for other causes.

Comment: @LittleGreenViper Yeah I've seen this message in other situations, but my project ran until i installed Xcode 10.2 (and with it macOS 10.14.4) that's why I thought I could have the same issue.

Comment: Lot of stuff changed. I'm not sure that I've seen all the impacts on my projects yet. I'm still updating them, one-by-one.

Comment: @FabioBerger you had the same issue as mine, dont forget to check your sdk, ur sdk/custom framework should be rebuild on the new environment (os 10.4.4 and xcode 10.2)

Comment: You were right. It disappears after I upgraded my mac. Thank you!!

Comment: excellent, that was it, updating the new macOS 10.4.4, brings it the new command tool for running the xcode 10.2.

Answer (score 3):

This issue happened because I update XCode to 10.2 without updating the MacOS to the latest and the sdk that I used also not updated. Apparently these steps had solved my issues :

1. Update your MacOS the latest[image: List item]
2. for my case even updating all the required updates not solving the crash issue. In that case don't forget to check if your affected SDK/framework already rebuild from the latest XCode (10.2), since The problem went away after I rebuild the SDK with the latest XCode (10.2).
3. For my case, we used jenkins to release the app, if the cloud still using old xcode and os, the .ipa will still crash. Need macos and xcode on jenkins cloud to be also updated.
4. Because updating the cloud will affect everything (near the release date) so either I roll back the os and xcode, or I use the old sdk/framework (before rebuild state). But using the second option will make it crash on simulator but atleast no crash issue if release the app.

Answer (score 2):

I updated my macOS as was suggested, but it did not help without the following change in the `Package.swift`:

```
- // swift-tools-version:4.2
+ // swift-tools-version:5.0
```